# What is the fastest classical "period-finding" algorithm that can replace the Quantum Fourier Transform in Shor's algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, quantum-computing

Shor's algorithm uses the Quantum Fourier Transform to find the period the function `a^x mod N` with "a" being a constant integer less than N and N being a semiprime. This function is periodic and has both a domain and image of all integers from 2 to N.

What is the fastest classical algorithm that could be used in place of the Quantum Fourier Transform in Shor's algorithm?

Comment: Can we assume the function is periodic?, What is the domain and the image of the function?

Comment: Yes, the function is periodic and both the domain and image are integers from 2 to N. Specifically in Shor's algorithm the function is: a^x mod N with "a" being a constant integer less than N and N being a semiprime.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what preconditions you know about the function, as pointed out by @nir shahir in the comments.

You might be interested in the Sparse Fourier Transform, which works when the periodic portion of the signal accounts for a significant portion of the total signal power.

The paper that broke this field open is:

> A. C. Gilbert, S. Guha, P. Indyk, S. Muthukrishnan, M. J. Strauss, Near-Optimal Sparse Fourier Representations via Sampling, *Proc. of the 2002 ACM Symposium on Theory of Computing* (STOC-2002):152--161.

There's a more recent survey paper of later developments that looks like it might be a good starting point:

> Anna C. Gilbert, Piotr Indyk, Mark Iwen, Ludwig Schmidt, “[Recent Developments in the Sparse Fourier Transform: A compressed Fourier transform for big data](https://people.csail.mit.edu/ludwigs/papers/sp14_sfft.pdf)”, *IEEE Signal Process. Mag.*, 31(5): 91-100, 2014.

Edited To Add:

The question was originally about finding the period of arbitrary functions.  OP later clarified that they mainly care about the function `a^x mod N`, which is not sufficiently sparse that you could use the Sparse Fourier Transform.  (At least, you wouldn't get anything useful out of the Sparse Fourier Transform with only $O((\log N)^k)$ samples.)  For `a^x mod N` the way `N` is defined in Shor's algorithm, you end up with a signal with $O(\sqrt N)$ harmonics, each of which contributes only approximately $O(1/\sqrt N$ of the total power.